# How long does the Gate-to-Gate airport transfer service in Frankfurt take?

Tags: short-connections, fra, airport-terminals

How much time would it take a transfer between Terminal 2, D-area/pier, non-Schengen EU arrival and Terminal 1 (Condor gates?), departure to non-Schengen, non-EU destination, if I use the FRA airport "gate-to-gate" paid transfer service?
I have exactly 60 minutes layover time, one ticket (Condor). They say the minimum transfer time is 45 minutes. Do they have some fast tracks through security checks, immigration, etc?

Comment: If you are on a single ticket don't waste money on the paid transfer service.

Comment: @chx OP might appreciate being on time more than any money savings.

Answer (score 1):

Each major airport has shortcuts, which can be used by staff. These shortcuts are used by the airline staff if some transit passengers are late but should be brought to the departure on time. This includes separate passport control and separate security check.

However, if you have the single ticket, you should not worry about layover. In case you previous flight is late, the airline will give you free tickets for the next flight.

Comment: Free tickets for the next flight, especially on an airline like Condor, could easily be the next day, if not longer.

Comment: The airline representative has the right to give tickets from another airline. You can ask kindly, and they will provide you with a nearest possible flight from the partner.